# resize and reserve in vector

Tags: c++, vector, dynamic-memory-allocation

Main question

Does `resize` for vector affect performance even if its capacity is bigger than its size?

---

For example, I want to make a code for pseudo code like following

```
const size_t size_a = 2;
const size_t i_max = 3;
vector<int> a(size_a) = random_vector;
vector<int> b;

for (size_t i=0; i<i_max; i++){
    patch_a_at_the_end_of_b;
}
```

So, `b` changes its size every loop but it will monotonically increase and I know the final size of `b`.

---

Firstly, I make a function `concat(a,b)` such that patch `a` to the end of `b`.

```
void concat(const vector<int> a, vector<int> &b){
    const size_t size_b = b.size();
    b.resize(size_b+a.size());
    for(size_t i=0; i<a.size(); i++)
        b[size_b + i] = a[i];
}
```

Note that we resize vector every time when `b` is called by `concat`.

Then, I add `b.reserve` in front of `for` loop in main function.

```
const size_t size_a = 2;
const size_t i_max = 3;
vector<int> a(size_a) = random_vector;
vector<int> b;
b.reserve(size_a*i_max);

for (size_t i=0; i<i_max; i++){
    concat(a,b);
}
```

---

Comment: Do you have to shout at the start of the question?

Comment: I changed it to normal font.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `b.reserve(size_b + size_a * i_max);` ?

Comment: `b = concat(a,b);` <-- but `concat` is defined as `void`. Apart of that, the reserve mechanism seems pretty logical.

Comment: A.S.H << since `b` is empty at the first place, `size_b=0`. I edited for your second comment.

Comment: `resize` should only allocate new memory if it needs to.  It doesn't naively allocate memory each and every time it's called.  Also, I believe you could have posted a much simpler code example of what you're asking instead of 3 pieces of disjointed code.  Is [this code](http://ideone.com/NwJBjH) a condensed version of your question?

Comment: Why not measure and see for yourself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The specification of `std::vector`s operations probably provide most of the answer to this question.

Firstly, `resize()` is specified as being `void resize(size_type n, value_type val = value_type())`, with requirements;

- If `n`  is less than the current size, the additional elements then the additional elements are removed and destroyed (i.e. if elements have a destructor, the destructor is invoked).
- If `n` is greater than the current container size, the content is expanded by inserting at the end as many elements as needed to reach the size of `n`. If `val` is specified, the new elements are initialized as copies of `val`, otherwise, they are value-initialized.
- If `n` ***is also greater*** (emphasis mine) than the current container capacity, an automatic reallocation of the allocated storage space takes place.

Note that nothing whatsoever is said about reducing the container capacity if its size is reduced.

Now, `reserve(size_type n)` is specified as requesting that the vector *capacity* be `n` or more elements, with requirements

- If n is greater than the current vector capacity, the function causes
  the container to reallocate its storage increasing its capacity to n
  (or greater).
- In all other cases, the function call does not cause a reallocation and the vector capacity is not affected.
- This function has no effect on the vector `size` and cannot alter its elements.

The second point here may be interpreted as saying that `reserve()` cannot be used to reduce capacity.

**Note:**   I'm paraphrasing in the above, but it is essentially a summary of what the standard requires of `resize()` and `reserve()`.

Putting those points together:   The only circumstance in which `resize()`  (or any other operation that increases the size of the vector) is required to increase capacity of the vector is if the new size exceeds the current capacity.

Beyond that, what happens is a quality of implementation concern.  However, one logical manner of implementation would be;

- `resize()` (and other operations that increase size of the vector) never increases capacity unless the new size exceeds current capacity
- `reserve()` never reduces capacity

In such an implementation, calling `reserve()` before doing operations that increase size of the vector would give a performance advantage (eliminating need for actual reallocation unless the size ever grows to exceed the capacity specified using `reserve()`).

Things would potentially be different if an implementation used a different approach, such as reducing capacity of a container at any stage (e.g. if a call of  `resize()` reduces the size, it also reduces the capacity).   This might be done in an attempt to minimise total memory usage of the container (i.e. not keeping additional capacity allocated for as long as the `vector` itself exists).    This would give a performance hit if the size of the vector oscillates in size (e.g. increases in some circumstances, decreases in others).

Comment: Thanks for your answer!